# How do I replace the windows explorer shell with some image during boot?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer, windows-registry

When I start the computer instead of opening `explorer.exe` I need to put some image or blank screen.

In registry if I change shell value in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` to `cmd.exe` , the cmd will come after bootup. Similarly can I replace with some batch file instead of value `explorer.exe`?

So, will this work to disable explorer.exe and put some background at the startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set *any* executable as the default shell of Windows.

As far as I remember, a batch file will not work, it needs to be a proper, executable [PE file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).

Comment: if u call cmd.exe through batch file it has no issues. but if i call other .exe through batch file how to know whether it working or not